# Zoo Visitor: delete all in member group + channel entries

Tags: zoo-visitor

I have a member group with 10,000 members. I need to delete all of those members plus all channel entries assigned to them.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up appending the url that shows the members in the control panel, so that I could view 1000 at a time from member group 5.

```
&group_id=5&perpage=1000
```

Comment: How does that help? Were you originally seeing 'all members'?

Comment: I was only seeing 50 or 100 members at a time. By adding that parameter to the url when viewing members, I can see and delete 1000 at a time.